# SVN: how to return to previous revision?

Tags: svn

A series of mistakes were made in a project I am working on. How do I revert back to a known working revision and build on top of that? Say I am at revision 15, but I want to go back to revision 10 -- and work on 10 onwards. I'm using Zend Studio.

Can I delete revisions that exist in SVN?

Comment: Strongly suggest you to look into the answer by @Unsigned.  The accepted answer is simply not an optimal solution. In brief, to reverse your faulty commit, you should use reverse merge, as SVN can do proper merge tracking too.  And it is possible to remove invalid revision, with way in Unsigned's answer.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From the command line:

```
svn up -r [revision_number]
```

Where [revision_number] is the revision you want to revert to.

And no, you cannot delete revisions that already exist in SVN.

Comment: @Ash - say I update back to revision 10, then make changes to it, then commit. Will I run into any problems since I was working on revision 10, but SVN is at 15 already?

Comment: No, you'll be comitting revision 16.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. When you revert to 10, the next time you commit, revision 16 will become the current revision. This will essentially bypass everything that was done in 11-15.

Comment: @Ash Are you sure? I'm pretty sure svn will treat this as a conflict. Sure you can just accept that all your changes are correct, but it's not a simple commit anymore.

Comment: @Dunes it's definitely possible that other working copies might become conflicted if the changes are significant. In that case, you would have to resolve the conflict(s) by accepting your own changes as you mentioned.

Comment: SVN will want you to update your working copy to HEAD before you can commit so this procedure will not work.
Better branch from a known revision: svn cp http://myrepos/oldbranch@10 svn cp http://myrepos/newbranch 
you then rename the newbranch back if you like.

Comment: example? do you leave the space between the r and the revision number or no? what about the brackets?

Answer (score 19):

You can simply do an update to revision using

```
svn up -r 10
```

But as Christoph has suggested this will **not let you commit the changes** as SVN needs you to update your working copy to HEAD before you can commit. What you can do instead is

```
svn merge -r HEAD:10 yourFile
svn ci yourFile -m "Reverting back to rev 10"
```

Comment: Hello. How can i do svn merge but instead of one file all files?

Answer (score 14):

Three options:

**Reverse merge: *(fastest, keeps bad revisions, adds new revision)***

```
svn merge $(REPO)@$(GOODREV) $(WC)
```

**SVN dump: *(removes bad revisions entirely)***

```
svnadmin dump $(REPO) -r 1:$(GOODREV) > dumpfile
svnadmin load $(NEWREPO) < dumpfile
# Now delete $(REPO), and use $(NEWREPO)
```

**Hand editing: *(removes bad revisions, unsafe, last resort)***

The only reason you might need this is if for some reason you have file-level access to the repository, but no shell access. Note that this has only been tested on SVN 1.6 and 1.7.

1. Update your working copy to `$(GOODREV)` (If left at `HEAD`, it will be unusuable after we finish.)
2. Take any steps to secure the repo from outside access. If it's attached to a web server, disconnect it now. Third-party accesses to the repo during this process can damage it.
3. Back up your repo. (Never hurts, just in case something goes wrong.)
4. Change the number in `db/current` to the `$(GOODREV)`. Be sure not to alter the `LF` line ending.
5. Delete all numbered *files* (not folders) in `db/revs/*/*` and `db/revprops/*/*` that are > `$(GOODREV)`
6. Delete `db/rep-cache.db`
7. Update your working copy to `HEAD`, which should now be equal to `$(GOODREV)`.

Note that if you are using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/), you must also complete these steps:

1. Delete all files in `%APPDATA%\TortoiseSVN\logcache\*`
2. Kill all instances `TSVNCache.exe` via the Task Manager. (There's usually one, but *could* be 2 on WinVista+ due to UAC security, which prevents elevated applications from interacting with a non-elevated `TSVNCache.exe`. The first time you open a `Save As...` dialog from an elevated application, an elevated `TSVNCache.exe` will spawn.)

This will fix the weird log display caused by TortoiseSVN's cache being in conflict with the new repo state.

Comment: Could you give example of the merge with the vars filled in?

Answer (score 1):

Get the docs from TortoiseSVN office site.

1. Use the revision log dialog
2. Use the merge dialog

I use method 2 and work fine on my side.

https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html